# How to enable monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on my HP ZBook laptop.

I try to connect ASUS VE248 monitor via HDMI-to-HDMI cable.

After monitor connected I can see "Could not enable monitor" notification poping though in Displays Settings second monitor appeared. No visual changes on monitor.
[image]

What can the reason for such behavior and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite straightforward: I just needed to select the "HDMI" source on the monitor with "sources" button...

For some reason I thought that since only a laptop is connected to monitor, source would be defined automatically, but no, by default the source is "DVI" and need to switch to "HDMI" manually.